# Swift. Detecting when facebook login viewcontroller is being dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, authentication, dismiss

I'm trying to detect when the facebook login viewcontroller gets dismissed so I can stop the loading animation. I implemented the facebook login SDK through firebase, and I'm logging in using this method:

```
@IBAction func facebookSignIn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    loginBtn.startLoadingAnimation()
    FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print("CustomFB Login Failed: ", err)
            self.loginBtn.stopLoadingAnimation()
            return
        }
    }
}
```

How would I detect when the login viewcontroller gets dismissed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple, you have put `stopLoadingAnimation()` in the wrong place.

```
@IBAction func facebookSignIn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    loginBtn.startLoadingAnimation()
    FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, err) in

        self.loginBtn.stopLoadingAnimation()
        //Facebook login is complet after Two case, failer and success. 

        if err != nil {
            print("CustomFB Login Failed: ", err)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Stop spinner login is under if condition, but user clicks on cancel then your spinner does not stop.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I didn't think of this, but it did the trick!